# Paradox to MySQL on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, paradox

Is there an app for this on mac?

Comment: am also looking for this. do share.

Comment: me too http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=1442 this one for windows

Comment: lol didn't realize it was my own post

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot, I haven't used it on the Mac but most linux apps will compile and install with no problems:

http://www.42.mach7x.com/2008/04/21/converting-paradox-tables-to-mysql-in-linux/

Check out http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Build-and-Run-Open-Source-Programs-on-Your-Mac-118094.shtml to reference compiling software on a Mac.